# Calculating average treatment effect for propensity score matching with MatchIt and Zelig packages in R

Tags: r, propensity-scores

Using the `lalonde` dataset provided with the `MatchIt` package, I'm running the following R commands (from the subclassification example code on the author's website: http://r.iq.harvard.edu/docs/matchit/2.4-20/Examples2.html) to find the average treatment effect (ATE) for the re78 income variable via subclassification propensity score matching:

```
library(MatchIt)
library(Zelig)

m.out2 <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + black + hispan + nodegree + 
                        married + re74 + re75, data = lalonde, 
                        method = "subclass", subclass = 4)


z.out3 <- zelig(re78 ~ re74 + re75 + distance, 
                      data = match.data(m.out2, "control"), 
                      model = "ls", by = "subclass")

x.out3 <- setx(z.out3, data = match.data(m.out2, "treat"), fn = NULL, 
                     cond = TRUE)

s.out3 <- sim(z.out3, x = x.out3)

summary(s.out3)
 sim x :
 -----
ev
      mean       sd      50%     2.5%    97.5%
1 7403.842 350.7007 7413.838 6745.717 8098.868
pv
         mean       sd      50%      2.5%    97.5%
[1,] 7491.131 6787.782 7329.752 -5936.341 20942.52

 sim x :
 -----
ev
      mean       sd      50%     2.5%   97.5%
1 4138.609 1170.197 4145.441 1872.314 6448.79
pv
         mean       sd      50%      2.5%    97.5%
[1,] 4157.933 5797.371 4031.378 -7585.696 15198.53

 sim x :
 -----
ev
     mean       sd      50%     2.5%    97.5%
1 4108.98 845.9136 4073.592 2415.578 5804.729
pv
         mean       sd      50%     2.5%   97.5%
[1,] 3910.667 4366.467 3914.451 -4408.87 12145.8

 sim x :
 -----
ev
      mean       sd      50%     2.5%    97.5%
1 6306.787 1656.057 6309.035 3035.061 9521.649
pv
         mean       sd      50%      2.5%    97.5%
[1,] 6318.831 6635.518 6652.653 -7352.725 18704.96
```

The code runs without error, however I don't understand the output from `summary(s.out3)` and the documentation is unhelpful. Are the four mean `ev` values equal to the expected ATEs for each of the four subclasses? Where is the ATE averaged over all four subclasses?

Comment: Is there a chance you answer your own question on this? I am sure people will find it helpful as Zelig's documentation is indeed patchy at this point.